# how to update Listdata with Linqpad and wcf?

Tags: wcf, linq, sharepoint-server

I am a lazy person, therefor I like to not scratch up a small concsole application if I don't need to.

I'd like to update a few listitems via Linqpad.

I can query the items just fine, but how do I update them? In my case I just need to replace the word "Neu" with "New" in a certain field.

```
//using OData calling /_vti_bin/listdata.svc
var ItemsToUpdate = Orders.Where(t => t.Status == "Neu")
foreach(var item in ItemsToUpdate)
{
  item.Status.Dump();
  item.Status = "New";
  imte.Status.Dump();
}
```

Normally I'd call Context.SaveChanges() but in LinqPad I haven't defined a context. How can I submit my changes to the list? You see, that I use Dump() before and after the newly assigned Status value of `New`. It goes like expected (neu New Neu New Neu New ....). The problem really just seems to be the submitting and saving of those changes.

Kind regards

Comment: yes, I tried, but there is no extensionmethod Update();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is as following:

```
foreach(var item in ItemstoUpdate)
{
  item.Status = "New";
  UpdateObject(item); 
}
SaveChanges();
```

I didn't know I had to use `UpdateObject(object)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just type SaveChanges(); directly.

Comment: I can, but the Update is not passed to the server. The data stays as it is.